# How to fix "BOOTMGR is compressed" via Mac OS X?

Tags: windows-7, mac, boot-camp, bootmgr

I've had Windows 7 on a Boot Camp partition on my iMac for a while now. All of a sudden, my BOOTMGR is compressed.

I've read countless solutions to this that involve using the Windows installation disk to run a repair and some other commands, but i think that's the easy way out. I want to know if there's a way to perform a similar task using Mac OS X itself or an app that runs in it - no DVD or USB booting necessary.

I've read about rEFIt, but it still requires me to reboot into a separate mode to perform operation. I feel that there can be a way to directly operate on the Boot Camp partition from within OS X, since that partition isn't in use by the system.

If I can't find a way to do this, I'll eventually try out the Windows DVD method, but I really want to know what you guys would do if all you had was OS X and the internet.